# Issue with CUDA array compaction using thrust zip_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust, stream-compaction

I'm having a confusing error when trying to compact multiple CUDA arrays using the thrust zip iterator. My case is simple: I have a thrust::vector of integers indicating the status of an object, and six vectors of floats indicating the object's position and velocity in 3D. When the the value of status (integer) vector element is 1, I want to remove the element from all vectors and shrink the vectors.

Following [this example](http://choorucode.com/2011/06/27/thrust-compact-multiple-vectors-using-predicate/), I utilize a 7-way tuple and a Predicate.

```
// Predicate
struct isTupleFlagged
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator() ( const PartTuple& tup )
    {
        const int x = thrust::get<0>( tup );
        return ( x == 1 );
    }
};

void ParticleSystem::RemoveFlaggedParticles()
{
        typedef thrust::device_vector< int >::iterator  IntDIter;
        typedef thrust::device_vector< float >::iterator  FloatDIter;
        typedef thrust::tuple< IntDIter, FloatDIter, FloatDIter, FloatDIter, FloatDIter, FloatDIter, FloatDIter >     PartDIterTuple;
        typedef thrust::zip_iterator< PartDIterTuple >  ZipDIter;

        ZipDIter newEnd = thrust::remove_if(    thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple( exit.begin(), x.begin(), y.begin(), z.begin(), vx.begin(), vy.begin(), vz.begin() ) ),
                                                thrust::make_zip_iterator( thrust::make_tuple( exit.end(), x.end(), y.end(), z.end(), vx.end(), vy.end(), vz.end() ) ),
                                                isTupleFlagged() );

        PartDIterTuple endTuple = newEnd.get_iterator_tuple();
        exit.erase(thrust::get<0>( endTuple ), exit.end());
        x.erase( thrust::get<1>( endTuple ), x.end() );
        y.erase( thrust::get<2>( endTuple ), y.end() );
        z.erase( thrust::get<3>( endTuple ), z.end() );
        vx.erase( thrust::get<4>( endTuple ), vx.end() );
        vy.erase( thrust::get<5>( endTuple ), vy.end() );
        vz.erase( thrust::get<6>( endTuple ), vz.end() );

}
```

However, this seems to erroneously remove extra elements. For example, when there is a single flagged object in a vector of 100, the post-compact size of the vectors is 52, not 99 as one would expect. What have I missed?

Comment: Do you think that the answer to this post [Type of return value of thrust::remove_if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269773/type-of-return-value-of-thrustremove-if) will help you?

Comment: Jack, that post is actually very helpful, I think I may be able to find a solution with that information. Thanks!

Comment: Marking as duplicate then.  If you disagree, post a new question that provides a *complete* example (SO expects this) including a generation of a test data set, as well as an indication of how you are determining how many items remain.  This should be a complete, compilable example that doesn't require any additions or modifications.  cut,copy,paste, compile, run is the idea.